# How far back do you use your version control and for what reason?

Tags: maintenance, version-control

Typically when i work on a project i only go back a few days or the last major change when i decide to do something drastic.

I sometimes notice i broke a test or a feature and overlooked it for a few weeks so i may go back a month or two and see if the feature or test is broken and trace down the week i broke it. Then find what change did it.

On a long term project over the span of a year. Do you actually go back 6+ months and if so why?

Answer (score 6):

We started using CVS 10 years ago for our non-mainframe code, and I migrated the whole lot to git about 6 months ago.  While mainly developing new things and maintaining existing versions, I have recently had to fix an unexpected issue in code put into production about 5 years ago.  Being able to pull out the codebase from version control and merge in our new build system, allowed for a rapid fix and modernizing it too.

Many decisions in our codebase was made before my time.  Being able to go back to see the code as it was then, with the comments, makes it easier to understand.

But, to answer your question - we want the complete history back to day one.

Comment: I second Thorbjørn: it is essential to keep history from day 1. You cannot predict when you are going to need it. But it supposes check in comments are sufficiently explanatory...

Comment: @asoundmove, why does it suppose comments are sufficiently explanatory?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: does it not? In my mind if the comments are not explanatory enough you may as well look for a needle in a haystack, not even knowing whether there is a needle there. Comments are what guides you to find what you need (check-in comments should say why or what is being checked-in).

Comment: @asoundmove, I am still not sure what you comment upon.  I am discussing how to look back on ancient versions to locate when a given snippet was added and in what context. Most VCS'es provide for seeing what version a given line was changed at.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Oh well, I'm showing how long since I used a VCS heh? But even with line number information, I have always liked to see the reason for a change in any given version. This can include a bug fix number, the reference to a new feature, maybe a proper specification or design document... I have found this to have been of great help when investigating ancient code. YMMV. Sometimes a given change spans several versions, the type of comment I talk about would allow you to trace through all those versions.

Comment: @asoundmove, you are a programmer and do not use a VCS?  Seriously?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: No, I have been a programmer, not been that for a while now, but still keeping a finger on the pulse.

Comment: Just as important is to also have the records of all the history tied to the ticket system.  Find a bug related to a five-year old change is one thing, but it can be much easier to deal with if the original bug report or feature request for that change is also available.

Comment: Being able to fix a bug in an older version is a GREAT answer. Especially for an old version of the product

Answer (score 1):

We still have the code of our years old versions. Because some **customers swear by their ancient, tested programs** and don't want to upgrade to our new versions.

So each time a major version is released we branch the old code. And the more important bugs are fixed in the current version plus in the older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Where I used to work, we had some very old version control - mid 90's I think, or something thatta'ways. Don't know when it started since (naturally) no one was interested in those parts, and true, it was in different control systems as time went by, but it was there.

The product is still being developed, and is still under VC. The "history available" in which most are interested is about two years (slow development cycle).